# creating a new column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `data frame` with 5 columns. Two of the columns are of type `datetime64[ns]`, called `Start_Time` and `End_Time`.

I wanted to create a new column in my `data frame` called `Overall_Time`.

The way I did this was:

```
df['Overall_Time'] = df['End_Time'] - df['Start_Time']
```

However, I get this message:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

So I tried this way:

```
df['Overall_Time'] = df.loc[:,'End_Time'] - df.loc[:,'Start_Time']
```

But get the same message as the first time.

So the problem is, it does create that new column in `df` but the message suggest that its copying (?) so I try using `.loc` and still says the same thing...
so how can I use `.loc` so that I dont get this message: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`
Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: is df is subset of others ? like df=df1.loc[condition]

Comment: df is the data frame with 5 columns, I want to make a new column in df by using 2 columns from it by subtracting them with each other. @Wen

Comment: You are looking for copy .